# netbeans 7.4 tomcat7: when deploying, where is the war file?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, war

just created a very simple web application using netbeans.  i was able to add tomcat 7 server and able to build and deploy.  the web application works.  my question is i thought when i did the "deploy", i was expecting my application's war file to be in the tomcat's webapps folder.  i didn't see it.  Tomcat's manager application does show it and i can run the application from it as well.  Should i just deploy the war file manually using tomcat manager app?

Thanks in advance,

Thomas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NetBeans doesn't create a war file when you run deploy. It just registers the "build" directory as a webapplication with Tomcat.

Check out `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost` there should be a file `yourapp.xml` Where `yourapp` is the "context path" you specified for your project ("Project Properties -> Run")

The XML file contains only single entry, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" docBase="/path/to/your/project/build/web" path="/yourapp"/>
```

Due to this configuration file, Tomcat is able to run your web application